# ubuntu 12.04 booting problems probably due to nvidia

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, nvidia, windows-7

I reinstalled windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my system 2 days back. Both OS were working fine . Yesterday I  Installed Nvidia Graphic card on windows 7  and I switched to ubuntu after rebooting it , ubuntu did not boot ( it says nouvea i2wc faill .... ).
I have installed ubuntu on a seperate partition

Comment: It could be that the registers aren't cleared properly and the state of it make the nouveau driver fail to initialize. Could you try turning your PC off completely, then pull the power plug, wait ~1 minute, then plug in the power again and try if you can boot Ubuntu (without starting Windows). If that still does not work, it is probably an update you applied in Ubuntu that caused this (kernel). Try booting an older kernel.

Comment: @qertvdijk i use a laptop

Comment: A laptop is a PC too. Just also remove the battery for a minute or so. Just to be sure.

Comment: Please describe the error in more details. Most probably there is no influence from windows drivers to linux as the systems are installed separately and Windows does not even read nor write linux partitions. Give us exact error message. Ad dto your question result of the Ctrl+Alt+F2 keypress - does new console login apears? If you installed a new graphics card, its completely different story.

Comment: @qertvdjk :o i know it man ,

Comment: @Dee sometimes it shows me the splash messages , sometimes a black screen and sometime the ubuntu loading dots .. and hung ,

Comment: ... and are you able to enter the console login by Ctrl+Alt+F2 keypress ?

Comment: Does this will help you to solve it? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @Dee U have seen link before , i tried to boot in nomodeset , but still hangs on the ubuntu dots

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10248/discussion-between-dee-and-neetz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  the long discussion was discovered, that here is a hybrid Graphics card Optimus in charge, so best option is to follow this link: ([Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)) and follow steps introduced by user Lekensteyn. Then you should get your card working.

Comment: Thanks  isaw the link , I know bumblebee needs to be installed ..but before i do so , i wanto to boot to GUI mode , so if i follow this to get the gui http://askubuntu.com/questions/104408/cant-use-nvidia-drivers-in-dell-inspiron-n5110  andtype this command   rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf i see there's no such file

Comment: this was in Ubuntu 11.10, you have a 12.04, where xorg.conf does not exist anymore by default. Read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there . Better to follow steps for your version of ubuntu.

Comment: Ok But I am surprised to see why my hardware doesn't support all of a sudden , coz i have been using ubuntu 12.10 for a year until last week it dint boot

Comment: This could be because of kernel updates, and kernel x nvidia driver mismatch. Did you try to run system with previous version of the kernel?

Comment: and how do i delete that configuration for 12.04 , where is it stored .. and if it is stored , is it safe to delte , the link says only to create and edit

Comment: yes , I did that also failed .. and I used the same iso file which i installed 1 year back

Comment: Sorry follow the 12.04 steps, or system you have... (12.04 or 12.10, there is a difference for hybrid Graphics cards) don't use steps for 11.10.

Comment: where do i get the thing , not able to find the file and essentially what does the file do

Comment: Again and last time. dont use any steps from different version of the Ubuntu. This will not work for your Gcard.

Comment: I meant where do i find for 12.04  , and i dont know the side effects .. I am totally a newbie

Comment: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: read link I originally posted (http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/58470) top-down everything. There are clear steps what you can do. There is nothing about xorg and 11.10.